# Entity Framework 6: FK cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've created a EF6 model from a database and in the database made sure that all FK constraints has a "ON DELETE NO ACTION" set. In the Model Browser I can verify that all associations is marked OnDelete None.

Still, when running the application I get an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Titles_dbo.Composers_ComposerId' on table 'Titles' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

I've searched high and low for a way to make the EF understand that there's no cascading deletes or updates in the database. All the solutions I've found is for Code-First scenarios with Fluent API and/or remove the OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention in the modelBuilder function. I can't get any of these to work, the OnModelCreating is not executed in a Database-First scenario.

Is there anyone that's run in to the same problem and have figured out how to solve it?